# HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error when using laravel with ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

this is my jquery ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});    
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/login',
            data: {
                'email' : $('#txtEmail').val(),
                'password' : $('#txtPassword').val(),
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
```

i add meta in my html

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

my route like this

```
Route::post('/login', 'PenggunaController@login');
```

and my controller like this

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PenggunaController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        $email = $request->email;
        echo $email;
    }
}
```

please, can someone help me, what wrong with my code ?

Comment: The 500 error implies the problem is with your server side code. It looks simple enough though. Try checking the responseText in the console, hopefully there will be an error you can diagnose

Comment: Or the PHP logs, if they are empty, check that error-reporting is enabled.

Comment: thank guys for the helps, it was fix, the problem is i unconscious delete controller class, lol.